# Issue with Android Studio WebView loading certain elements on a webpage

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-webview

I am using Androids `WebView` class to create a native application that emulates a native android application of my website.

Our website uses some pretty modern methods within the javascript and in older versions of chrome, the log in `Button` isnt shown and errors are thrown, even on a desktop. This can be alleviated by updating chrome to a newer/newest version.

My question is, is Chrome the browser that Android's `Webview` uses? and if so is there a way to update the version of chrome within it?

(edit) I have done a good bit of research to no avail. Below is my code from my `MainActivity.java` from Android Studio if it helps:

```
package com.afi.helix;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.webkit.WebSettings;

import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView WebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

    WebSettings webSettings = WebView.getSettings();
    WebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    WebView.loadUrl("my localhost url");
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(WebView.canGoBack()) {
        WebView.goBack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
}
```

##########################################################################

One more note: on  the device I am testing on, I can load the application no problem via the chrome application, the issue is with opening it within the WebView in my android studio application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is Chrome the browser that Android's webview uses?*

- Android is controlled through Google, Google Chrome is its Browser, `WebView` is a light `widget` and no browser based on `SDK` but extended by external updates - Thus, **NO** but related.

Sidenote:

> Android 4.4 KitKat first introduced a Chromium-based WebView component
> in
> 2013.

---

*... And if so is there a way to update the version of chrome within it?*

- Through Google Play Store depending on device.

> Although WebView has been based on Chromium since Android 4.4, the
> Chromium layer is now updatable from Google Play.
>
> As new versions of Chromium become available, users can update from
> Google Play to ensure they get the latest enhancements and bug fixes
> for WebView, providing the latest web APIs and bug fixes for apps
> using WebView on Android 5.0 and higher.

I want to refer the last quote from another SO-Post posted by [@Fahim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28922990/does-the-android-webview-version-depends-on-the-sdk-or-the-device).

---

**Add to WebView in Code:**

Additional Settings I would at to your `WebView` in `MainActivity.java`:

```
WebSettings webSettings = WebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Comment: Im relatively new to android app development and android studio as a whole, however the device I am using doesnt have the webview application installed from the play store. If I were to download it from the playstore and keep it up to date, would it in turn keep my reference to it in my app up to date? I am going to attach my mainActivity.java code in my main post above

Comment: No, as I said. Depending on your device. If you can't update it on the other the device it will use the one that is available. These updates are automatically by standard on close to every device. Thus it will work on some but not on every. Hope it helped to understand. It's comparable to APIs, some widget works on API 24 and higher for e.g. and others don't. If your website is too new, then the fault isn't at Android or the App Project. More on the brand new stuff you are using. Options, remove it or wait till it is available for more Chrome Version in relation to devices

Comment: Okay yes that makes more sense. I'll give it a try and see what happens. Its just frustrating since I can open the site via my chrome browser on the tablet, just not within the webview

Comment: I updated my answer. Try to add this code to your MainActivity.java. Probably you can see your JavaScript stuff. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! will add and further debug

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to mark the answer as correct to improve stackoverflow and help others facing the same problems or questions :) Thanks